# apache configuration extension doesn't work with https

Tags: apache

I have an extension to httpd.conf. I am using it for aliases and changing root:
The original root was set to `/data/www/html` and I need it to be `/data/www/pages`. For several reasons I do not want to touch the original `httpd.conf`, therefore, I created the `custom_config.conf`

custom_config.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>  
    DocumentRoot /data/www/pages
    Alias "/blah_blah" "/data/www/blah_blah"

    <Directory "/data/www/pages">
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

With this, I can access `http` but not `https`. I tried `<VirtualHost *:443>` and restarted the httpd of course, but still not working. I am not an expert with Apache, but I think it has to do something with `ssl.conf` that is under `conf.d` forlder; same place I put my `custom_config.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Check and make sure the alias extension is enabled:

`LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so`

and then try to set your alias like below:

`Alias /blah_blah/ "/data/www/blah_blah"`

Comment: Thanks Mehdi Where do I check for LoadModule?

Comment: You can search for `LoadModule` in the httpd.conf file, if it is commented out you can add that line in the beginning of your custom config file if you don't want to touch the original httpd.conf, or un-comment it out in the original file.

Comment: I tried that but I get:
```Starting httpd: [Tue Apr 19 11:54:32 2016] [warn] module alias_module is already loaded, skipping```

Comment: Try to look at the log, or check if any error is being shown in the output when you restart apache.

Comment: This turned out to be 100% internal company's configuration. Thank you very much for your help, the issue is resolved now

Comment: @SarahA What was the issue ?

Comment: It felt under the security and limitation on what we can/cannot override; 100% custom configuration that wasn't obvious